# Detect touches within UIScrollView and CATilerLayer

Tags: ios, ios4, uiscrollview, uitouch, catiledlayer

How can i detect the touch (x,y) of my pdf rendered in the ScrollView.
To be clear: I want the x,y of the pdf not of the screen.

Hope someone knows this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried - `(CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view` ?  If you put the view that the PDF is in, it should work…

Comment: No this doesnt work. It places the marker right, but when i zoom it's at a different place.

Comment: Is the pdfView in a UIScrollView?  If so, you can use `- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated` or `- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated` by creating a CGRect with the origin.x and origin.y of where the touch is.